# Titanium apps allowed on the iphone in 2011?

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator

If I develop a Titanium app for the iphone is it still allowed, as I heard that Apple has banned third party tools again in 2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently my titanium app is still in app store ;)

Comment: Does this mean that if I create a new app using titanium it will not be rejected by apple because it is made using Titanium?

Comment: Correct, it won't be rejected.

Comment: yup, we have dozens of updates/new apps accepted every day :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be allowed on the store because Titanium takes the code you write in JavaScript creates native code from it. Titanium even creates an XCode project file that you can open up, edit, etc. It's in the Build->iPhone directory.